# sending client side parameter to jQuery Rad ToolBar Controls

Tags: c#, jquery, telerik, client-side, server-side

I have a Radtoolbar control and some buttons that each of them is validated with Value option of control. In client side (OnClientClick event), jQuery function works fine. But, I want to call my jQuery function from server side which i am able to do aslo.

My real problem is that the jQuery function takes 2 parameters that I need to send from server side in a way that jQuery functions properly and I don't know what type of parameters it takes and how to make it.

Here is the jQuery function

```
function Tool_ClientButtonClicked(sender, args) {
      var p = args.get_item().get_value();
      ...
      ... 
}
```

How can I know the type of args?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a exact solution to my problem. So, I changed the scenario a little.

I send a parameter in order to understand if function is called throw the Server side or client side and passed the required param could fit to my situation with a simple if() else clause.